# VerifyCache in angularjs

Tags: javascript, web, angularjs

I have a certain angularjs service below..

```
angular.service('SubmitPayment', function($resource){
  return $resource('api/SubmitPayment', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false, verifyCache: false}
  });
});
```

anyone knows what does verifyCache do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of AngularJS had this option:

> verifyCache – {boolean=} – If true then whenever cache hit occurs, the object is
>   returned and an async request will be made to the server and the resources as
>   well as the cache will be updated when the response is received.

See line 7360, http://code.google.com/p/freality/source/browse/trunk/space/war/angular.js?r=105

Quote from Vojta: "We got rid off whole $resource caching." -- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/qWQyiXNNjqs/OMquMSVIF58J

The current code for the $resource service doesn't have this option:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L43

I think you can now manipulate the headers that are sent instead.